# Finding limit of $\sin(x^2/2)/\sqrt{2}\sin^2(x/2)$ as $x\rightarrow0$

Tags: limits, functions, limits-without-lhopital

Can anybody help me find the limit as $x$ tends to $0$, for $$\frac{\sin(x^2/2)}{\sqrt{2}\sin^2(x/2)}.$$ How can I simplify the expression or use equivalent transformations to find a limit (without using L'Hospital)?

Comment: Please refer to [this guide on how to typeset maths on this site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It's pretty hard to understand what is your expression you are working with

Comment: Use Taylor expansions.

Comment: HINT:  Note that $$\frac{\sin(x^2/2)}{\sqrt2 \sin^2(x/2)}=\left(\frac{\sin(x^2/2)}{x^2/2}\right)\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\left(\frac{x/2}{\sin(x/2)}\right)^2\left(\frac{1}{(x/2)^2}\right)$$Can you finish now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will be using just one fact to solve this, and that is,

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ \sin x}{x} = 1$$

**So lets start!** 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\sin \frac {x^2}{2}}{\sqrt{2} \; \sin^2 \frac {x}{2}}$$

Now, Multiply and divide by, $\frac{x^2}{2} \;$  and $(\frac {x}{2})^2$

The $\frac{x^2}{2}$ term in the denominator along with $\sin \frac {x^2}{2}$ in the numerator tends to **ONE**. And so is the case with the $(\frac {x}{2})^2$ in the numerator and $\sin^2 \frac {x}{2}$ in the denominator.

After that we see that the remaining $x^2$ terms cancel out (because we have one both in the numerator and the denominator).

Resulting in the answer (*cue the drumroll*) $$\sqrt 2$$

Edit: I have included the steps taken just as a measure[image]

Comment: The $\sqrt 2$ which is in the denominator stays out of our calculation. After simplifying we get $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin \frac {x^2}{2}}{\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}} = 2$$.. and that $2$ cancels with $\sqrt 2 $ to give the stated answer

Comment: Ok. I will attach all detailed steps

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much.

Comment: yeah I've edited my answer to show the method. Hope you like it! **If you still have questions feel free to ask!** ((*Otherwise upvote and accept the answer* :p))

Comment: Thank you very much. Maybe you know any good source when one can get accustomized with these set of problems? I accepted the answer, but cannot upvote you as I don't have enough reputation points yet.

Comment: I actually learnt limits on my own from many books.. but those books are rather advanced.. If you're looking for questions then there's this site called https://www.embibe.com/... try searching for "limits" on there and solve the questions! Happy studying!

Answer (score 0):

As $\dfrac{\sin x}x=1$, in multiplicative expressions you can replace $\sin x$ by $x$.

Hence

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin\left(\dfrac{x^2}2\right)}{\sqrt2\,\sin^2\left(\dfrac x2\right)}
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\dfrac{x^2}2}{\sqrt2\,\left(\dfrac x2\right)^2}=\sqrt2.$$